# BlackBerry Push Service for in-house app

Tags: blackberry, push-notification

We have an app that is developed for a client. The client **doesn't want the app to be available on BlackBerry World**. So we have deployed the app on the corporate network.

The app has BlackBerry Push Service enabled and till now we have been testing it using the [BlackBerry Push Service (Evaluation)](https://www.blackberry.com/profile/?eventId=8121) which is valid for 4 months. In order to have a no-limit validity, will the [BlackBerry Push Service (Production)](https://www.blackberry.com/profile/?eventId=8207) be helpful?

**Edit:** Our app runs on a BIS plan

Comment: Does the customer have a BES and if so, are all the BlackBerry devices which will use this on the BES?

Comment: No, Customer have BIS.